# Cannot close popup after cloning div. Bind()? JQUERY

Tags: jquery, function, popup, clone

How can I activate a click event after cloning a div named `.popup` , then clicking on a span named `#close` that is designed to close `.popup`?

Clicking on it currently does nothing. I understand that the div has been created after the page initialises, I just need to know how to bind this to the page so it is recognised when it is clicked upon.

**JavaScript:**

```
$('span#close').click(function () {
            $('.popup').fadeOut(1000);
        });
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="popup">
    <span id="close">Close</span>
    <!-- content -->
</div>
```

Comment: In the code that creates the pop-up, add the close function. For example, when you bind the click function to the open button, add the span#close click function right before you close the open function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your suggestions, the `.on()` handler, I could not get this working, no idea why, so I decided to use @faino 's suggestion.

I created the containing div in the html and set its property to `display:none`, this div also contained the `span#close` which is used to close the pop up.

When an item was cloned, it was appended to that containing div, and when I clicked on the `span#close`, it removed the cloned item and set the containing divs property back to `display:none`

This way, the `span#close` is not cloned and does not need the event exposed again.

Again, thanks for all your answers!

Answer (score 1):

You're likely looking for the [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) event exposed by jQuery - you *could* use [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) but this is deprecated and highly discouraged now.

So, something like:

```
$('span#close').on('click', function(e) { });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$("span#close").on("click", function(){
   $('.popup').fadeOut(1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy events while cloning. See [this](http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/01/copy-events-from-one-element-to-another) good article. Also remember that `ID` attribute must be unique in document. So after cloning element make sure you don't have duplicate elements with equal id's.